# How to use sed to remove certain text base on regular expression

Tags: sed

I got a text file with contents like below

```
2012/03/15 : "Password":"@#4JF9u92r","Name":"John"
```

I wish to use sed to change the above to

```
2012/03/15 : "Password":"XXX","Name":"John"
```

I have tried the following command

```
cat log.txt | sed 's/\("Password":\"\)\(.*\)\(\",\"Name\":\)/\1XXX/'
```

But it gives me

```
2012/03/15 : "Password":"XXX"John"
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should slightly change your `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\("Password":\"\).*\(\",\"Name\":\)/\1XXX\2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below regex is the base one, place necessary escape characters

```
(\s"Password":")(.*?)(","Name":"(.*?)")
```

Replace with `\1XXX\3`

After placing proper escape characters, I think it should be something like this.

```
cat log.txt | sed '\(s/\"Password\":\"\)\(.*?\)\(\",\"Name\":\"\(.*?\)\"\)/\1XXX\3/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo '2012/03/15 : "Password":"@#4JF9u92r","Name":"John"' |
sed 's/\("Password":"\)[^"]*/\1XXX/'
2012/03/15 : "Password":"XXX","Name":"John"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more concise...but might not work if password contain the " character..